# After party briefcase code

Tags: alphametic

Jack is a programmer working in an IT company. One day he arrives at his workplace and sees a briefcase on the table with a note attached to it that says: "g00d and 3v1l". He realizes - this must be his coworkers, who put it there. They had a party yesterday and he might have had a little bit too much to drink, so he started bragging about how he hacked his friend's email (even thought he just guessed his secret question), and how he could hack anything if he wanted to. Now to avoid looking like a fool it seems like he has to open this case... The case has a 4-digit code on it.

Help Jack solve this puzzle and pick a code to the case.

Tip 1:

> "and" could be spelled "4nd", but why is it not?

Tip 2:

> the whole thing could have all sorts of weird symbols in it if it was true leetspeak, but it's limited to letters and numbers...

Added after initial post:

Tip 3:

> it would be nice if the message didn't have those pesky "g,v,l" letters, but oh...

Tip 4 (first digit):

> the first digit is 3.

The answer:

> The code is "3095". "g00d", "3v1l" are in fact numbers with base of 36 (10 digits and 26 letters of English alphabet) so they correspond to "746509", "180201" in decimal. Now the "and" word is of course a bitwise AND operation, which gives decimal 140297. Now you convert that number back to 36 base representation and you get string "3095".

P.S. Sorry if it was too ambiguous. It was hard for me to tell if it was dead easy or very hard because I thought that up. Actually, I knew it was hard, but after Tip #3... not so much. I mean, just look at Mathias711's answer, who would have thought of that :O, that would be definitely a harder way to hide the password.

Comment: 0031 seems to cross the mind, but that would be tooooo easy

Comment: nope, but I will add more tips as the time passes.

Comment: *E) Not enough information given.* I could probably make up a "plausible" explanation for many, many codes with the little there is to go on here.

Comment: @Geobits I will add more information later. It just seemed very obvious to me where to start, but that's probably because I made this up :)

Comment: added 3rd tip which should give you the right direction.

Comment: another tip coming in like 30 minutes, but I hope people get it before that :)
Also I very much appreciate everyone participating and I will up vote good answers as soon as I get enough rep.

Comment: I'm agreeing with everyone else.   This is not a well-formed puzzle because it could be anything.   So it is not a good question and deserves a downvote.

Comment: Alright, you decide then, I'll post the answer shortly.

Comment: It was nearly impossible to guess the answer in the first place. Hints are ok but they don't have to give critical information

Comment: @AndreaGottardi it was my first question here, I just thought of this cool idea and I guess I didn't think enough about giving the right clues. Oh well, at least I tried.

Comment: I am not saying it is a bad riddle, because it can be tricky and challenging for many of us :) Maybe it needs a slightly better clue management :D

Comment: Maybe a hint towards the base 36 (which is uncommon) would resolve this. I thought it was good. Keep em coming please! :D

Comment: @d'alar'cop well, Tip #3 was supposed to be that, but I guess it was too subtle.

Comment: Good idea for a puzzle. +1 and VTR. I'd suggest some kind of way for the solver to know when they have the right answer (eg a hash/checksum).

Answer (score 6):

> g00d has a MIDI representation of **1942** according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g00d). 3v1l is a bit more complicated, but it turned out to be a [molecule](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore.do?structureId=3v1l)! The EC code is **3718**. Adding that up gives:

**Answer:**

> 5560

or, if you have the logical (and bitwise I suppose it is called) AND it gives :

**answer:**

> 0000, because no bits are the same

about the hints:

> I used the hints, because 'and' is the + or AND operator (and should not be written as 4nd) and changing any of the other letters to something leetspeek, it will change the whole outcome.

Comment: Very clever, but this is not the right code. You are very close in your assumptions about leetspeak though.

Comment: +1 for showing that the puzzle didn't contain enough information, twice

Answer (score 2):

> Given the hints we have, it's bound to be 0031 (or a variation of four-digit-numbers containing 0, 0, 3 and 1), as per the "leetspeak" on the note. g**00**d and **3**v**1**l.

Comment: that would be too easy, nope, not that simple, it is kinda simple if you think about it, but not this simple :)

Comment: Hence me saying "given the hints we have". Unless of course I am missing something obvious!

Comment: It's not that obvious, you might find more tips in the information about Jack.

Comment: well, I also tried to turn g00d into 7004 and 3v1l into 322112 and AND those, that'd give 0584 but would be a stretch.

Comment: 0584 is also not the right answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is of course

> 1337, because every 4-digit code in an IT company is 1337.

Comment: was worth a try, but it's not the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

First **(wrong)** try:

> Supposing `AND` stands for "**sum**" I think:
>  **`0615`** 
>  Because i changed all letters with corresponding ASCII code, and sum every letter in the word (`147 + 0 + 0 + 144 = 291` and  `3 + 166 + 1 + 154 = 324`). Adding them gives `615`

Second try (thanks to @No. 7892142):

> Changing even digits to ASCII, result is increased by 240, giving
>  `855`

Comment: Nice try, but it is a little more complicated.

Comment: Might wanna change the digits to ASCII, too, in that attempt.

Comment: I don't think it is correct anyway, because Rusty said it is more complicated

Comment: Still not right, I should have omitted "a little" in "a little more complicated" :) Check the third tip, it might set you on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the answer you're going for is

> 3377

since that's just the decimal form of the hexadecimal

> <s>g</s>00d 3<s>v</s>1<s>l</s> (00d31)

However, there's no way to be sure. I'm still not a fan of the ambiguity in this.

Comment: not the correct answer, but this is the hottest answer so far.

Comment: That illustrates the point I made in the comments above. There's a plausible explanation for basically anything, and no way to know what's right. If it were me, I'd just bust open the case with a screwdriver or hammer. If that didn't work, a four-digit brute force would be a better "hacker" solution.

Comment: I have to agree with Geobits and must add that the last "hint" didn't help in reaching the answer at all, it just plainly is a part of the answer with no explanation to it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't think of a way to get any closer to the answer, without making it immediately obvious, the tip #3 comes as close as it gets. I am sure you will find it making more sense when you see the answer. Try and find more sense in Tip #3